tikz diagram skier on a slope
is it possible to reproduce this schema with tikzpicture ?

This is what I tried :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%,pgf}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
%\usetikzlibrary{through}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,shadows}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the horizontal line
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5, 0) -- (9, 0);

    % Draw the slopes
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[thick] (5.5, 1.25) -- (7.5,0);

    % Draw the vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0) -- (5.5,1.25);

    % Labels for points
    \node at (0, -0.2) {A};
    \node at (2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (2.5, -0.3) {I};
    \node at (5.5, 1.5) {C};
    \node at (5.5, -0.3) {J};
    \node at (7.5, -0.3) {D};

    % Vectors
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,0.5) node[left] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};

    % Angle
    \coordinate[label=below:] (A) at (2.5,1.25);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (C) at (2.5,0);
    \draw pic [draw,-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=12pt,angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--A};

    % Skier on the slope
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.625) circle (0.15); % Head
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.625) -- (1.25, 0.1); % Body
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.4) -- (1.1, 0.3); % Left arm
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.4) -- (1.4, 0.3); % Right arm
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.1) -- (1.1, 0); % Left leg
    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.1) -- (1.4, 0); % Right leg

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The result :


In case you don't need a human skier: there is a ski duck available from https://github.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2017/blob/master/ulrikes-duck-pond/ski-duck-UF.tex (drawn by @ UlrikeFischer)

Besides tikz, angles and \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta} you don't need any other package to run your code. I'll comment that out for you, as it's very disturbing when compiling your copied code ...

Do you want the Skier moving up the slope ?? Seems a bit magical to me without seeing history ...

For the Skier you have several more optiones, e.g. a) Place an image there (\includegraphics as a node's text), b) Use a simple scribble of an abstracte Skier (do it on paper first, then transfer), c) find a SVG drawing, include it (see ctan.org for SVG). // Examples for scribbles: https://www.123rf.com/photo_59310794_downhill-skiing-vector-sketch-icon-isolated-on-background-hand-drawn-downhill-skiing-icon-downhill.html

yeah, I want a Skier moving up the slope pls

Thank you, I did it

The boring solution:
use a skier from the fontawesome5package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%,pgf}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
%\usetikzlibrary{through}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,shadows}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the horizontal line
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5, 0) -- (9, 0);

    % Draw the slopes
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[thick] (5.5, 1.25) -- (7.5,0);

    % Draw the vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0) -- (5.5,1.25);

    % Labels for points
    \node at (0, -0.2) {A};
    \node at (2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (2.5, -0.3) {I};
    \node at (5.5, 1.5) {C};
    \node at (5.5, -0.3) {J};
    \node at (7.5, -0.3) {D};

    % Vectors
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,0.5) node[left] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};

    % Angle
    \coordinate[label=below:] (A) at (2.5,1.25);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (C) at (2.5,0);
    \draw pic [draw,-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=12pt,angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--A};

    \node[rotate=55] at (1,0.7) {\Large\faSkiing};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The more fun variation:
Take Ulrike's ski duck from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2017/master/ulrikes-duck-pond/ski-duck-UF.tex
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{finnlandblue}{RGB}{0,53,128}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the horizontal line
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5, 0) -- (9, 0);

    % Draw the slopes
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[thick] (5.5, 1.25) -- (7.5,0);

    % Draw the vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0) -- (5.5,1.25);

    % Labels for points
    \node at (0, -0.2) {A};
    \node at (2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (2.5, -0.3) {I};
    \node at (5.5, 1.5) {C};
    \node at (5.5, -0.3) {J};
    \node at (7.5, -0.3) {D};

    % Vectors
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,0.5) node[left] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};

    % Angle
    \coordinate[label=below:] (A) at (2.5,1.25);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (C) at (2.5,0);
    \draw pic [draw,-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=12pt,angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--A};

    % from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2017/master/ulrikes-duck-pond/ski-duck-UF.tex
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.1,xscale=-1,rotate=-33,xshift=-15cm,yshift=-1.3cm]
    \path[draw=LightPink,fill=Silver] (7.352, 1.5683).. controls (7.4712, 1.5799) and (7.5811, 1.5204) .. (7.5974, 1.4352).. controls (7.6137, 1.3501) and (7.5304, 1.2715) .. (7.4112, 1.2599) -- (0.1723, 0.5274).. controls (0.169, 0.5271) and (0.1627, 0.5264) .. (0.1534, 0.5255).. controls (-0.0506, 0.5056) and (-1.658, 0.3693) .. (-2.2261, 0.963).. controls (-2.294, 1.034) and (-2.2685, 1.1308) .. (-2.1691, 1.1793).. controls (-2.0697, 1.2278) and (-1.9342, 1.2096) .. (-1.8663, 1.1386).. controls (-1.5009, 0.7567) and (-0.3176, 0.7906) .. (0.1104, 0.8355) -- cycle;
    \duck[santa=finnlandblue!80!black, jacket=gray, tshirt=white,body=LightGoldenrod2!70!RosyBrown1,scale=3]
    \path[draw=LightPink,fill=Silver] (7.202, 0.9722).. controls (7.3269, 0.9846) and (7.442, 0.9211) .. (7.4592, 0.8302).. controls (7.4763, 0.7394) and (7.3889, 0.6557) .. (7.264, 0.6432) -- (-0.3196, -0.138).. controls (-0.323, -0.1384) and (-0.3296, -0.1391) .. (-0.3394, -0.1401).. controls (-0.5531, -0.1613) and (-2.237, -0.3067) .. (-2.8321, 0.3266).. controls (-2.9033, 0.4023) and (-2.8765, 0.5056) .. (-2.7725, 0.5573).. controls (-2.6683, 0.6091) and (-2.5264, 0.5896) .. (-2.4553, 0.514).. controls (-2.0724, 0.1065) and (-0.8327, 0.1427) .. (-0.3844, 0.1906) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



@JohnKormylo Is there an advantage of sloped for a standalone node which is not part of path?

This would only work if the node was part of the path

@JohnKormylo (which would be an interesting alternative approach in case you feel like writing an answer)

It turns out that \faSkiing is alreacy rotated, so you would still have to guess the angle to compensate.

@JohnKormylo \faSkiingNordic :) (but doesn't look as dynamic as the alpine skier)

Well, he is going uphill.

Indeed! We really need to know the initial speed of the skier to choose the appropriate icon :)

As suggested by SamCarter...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%,pgf}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
%\usetikzlibrary{through}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,shadows}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the horizontal line
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5, 0) -- (9, 0);

    % Draw the slopes
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[thick] (5.5, 1.25) -- (7.5,0);

    % Draw the vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0) -- (5.5,1.25);

    % Labels for points
    \node at (0, -0.2) {A};
    \node at (2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (2.5, -0.3) {I};
    \node at (5.5, 1.5) {C};
    \node at (5.5, -0.3) {J};
    \node at (7.5, -0.3) {D};

    % Vectors
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,0.5) node[left] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};

    % Angle
    \coordinate[label=below:] (A) at (2.5,1.25);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (C) at (2.5,0);
    \draw pic [draw,-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=12pt,angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--A};

    \path (A) -- (B) node[midway, sloped, above, inner sep=0pt] {\Large\faSkiingNordic};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



is it possible to reproduce this schema with tikzpicture ?

Yes, as you've seen already. Here is a way to do it via my scribble suggestion B)
1. Scribble the skier uphill
I did what I wrote: sketched it with pen on paper. Though I could have scanned it, I just recreated it as a bitmap, with focus on upslope and relevant posture, and with mouse jitter, without smoothing:

2. Converting it to TikZ
It's a bit tricky, as pixel coordinates increase to the right AND downwards, while TikZ uses mathematical conventions (to the right AND upwards). To simplify my work I:

mirrored the image at the horizon (so it's upside down)
read pixel coordinates with the mouse cursor (e.g. 109/227px) and simply divided by 100 (1.1/2.3cm) for TikZ

Now you have a tikzle as a kind of line art ...

to reuse certain coordinates I put (A) and (C) for hip and head
and a variable shoulder coordinate at (B)


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}


\begin{document}
 % ~~~ sketch copy: inverted bmp, px/100 ~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sh/.style={pos=.7,inner sep=0},
    hd/.style={draw,fill=black,circle,
               inner sep=0,minimum size=1mm},
 ]
    % ~~~ skies ~~~~~~~
    \draw (  0,  0) -- (2.3,1.3);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) -- (2.3,1.9);
 
    % ~~~ feet + legs ~~~
    \draw (1.3,0.9) -- (1.1,0.8) -- 
          (1.3,1.4) -- (1.3, 1.9) coordinate(A);
    \draw (1.7,1.5) -- (1.4,1.3) -- (A);
 
    % ~~~ spine ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) -- node[sh] (B) {} (2,2.8) coordinate (C);
    
    % ~~~ arms+sticks ~~~~
    \draw (B) -- (3.2,2.5) -- (2.6,1.1);
    \draw (B) -- (2.8,2.7) -- (2.1,2);
    
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~
    \node[hd] at (C) {}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

3. Where to go from here?
Many options. E.g. you could:

put the code inside a \pic, so you can place myrades of skiers
parametrize it more, e.g. assign each absolute coordinate to \coordinate, so you can manipulate it easier
impact on line widths, perhaps even schange its line style with decorate or so (though that's more limited than from using brushes in raster-drawings)
introduce caps or tips at line ends
turn straight lines into bends, e.g. by replacing some -- with to[out=,in=]
... the sky's the limit, not the skier ;-)

EXAMPLE:

    % ~~~ spine ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) to[out=70,in=190] node[sh] (B) {} (2,2.8) coordinate (C);
    
    % ~~~ arms+sticks ~~~~
    \draw (B) to[out=2,in=130] (3.2,2.5) -- (2.6,1.1);
    \draw (B) to[out=2,in=130] (2.8,2.7) -- (2.1,2);



is it possible to reproduce this schema with tikzpicture ?

Yes, as you've seen already. Here is a way to do it via my SVG suggestion C)
Now, this one is simple, as it has been asked and answered before specifically for a skier, AND exhaustively for SVG to Tikz, see e.g. herein.
(For sake of completeness and for not getting lost inside comments I put this as a separate solution approach.)


is it possible to reproduce this schema with tikzpicture ?

Yes, as you've seen already. Here is a way to do it via my answer in comment A)
1. Get an image
So I found an uphill skier on a sign. Cur it out, filled white with black, deleted background to make it transparent. Saved as skierimg.png :

BTW, it's no big deal to redraw such a line art with some drawing tool or TikZ.
2. Adjusting your code

using package graphicx
calling the image inside a \node
and yes, you could rotate it a few degrees via node or includeimage ...


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}


    %%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%,pgf}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
%\usetikzlibrary{through}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,shadows}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the horizontal line
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5, 0) -- (9, 0);

    % Draw the slopes
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[thick] (5.5, 1.25) -- (7.5,0);

    % Draw the vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (2.5,1.25);
    \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0) -- (5.5,1.25);

    % Labels for points
    \node at (0, -0.2) {A};
    \node at (2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (2.5, -0.3) {I};
    \node at (5.5, 1.5) {C};
    \node at (5.5, -0.3) {J};
    \node at (7.5, -0.3) {D};

    % Vectors
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
    \draw[->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,0.5) node[left] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};

    % Angle
    \coordinate[label=below:] (A) at (2.5,1.25);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:] (C) at (2.5,0);
    \draw pic [draw,-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=12pt,angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--A};

    % Skier on the slope
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.625) circle (0.15); % Head
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.625) -- (1.25, 0.1); % Body
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.4) -- (1.1, 0.3); % Left arm
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.4) -- (1.4, 0.3); % Right arm
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.1) -- (1.1, 0); % Left leg
%    \draw[thick] (1.25, 0.1) -- (1.4, 0); % Right leg

    \node at (1,.9) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{skierimg.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

